# Error: Unable to resolve @nrwl/web:dev-server

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, nomachine-nx

how do i fix this error when i try to run my script to start my app i get the error Cannot find executor 'dev-server' with the path to the executor.json

I tried running yarn dev:ess but i get the following error Cannot find executor 'dev-server

Comment: what kind of app is it? in the new NX versions, you need to use different executors. E.g, for a react app, you now have to use "@nrwl/webpack:dev-server"